# Visualizer error in IBM Q Experience Beta

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I am noticing some erroneous behavior coming from the visualizer in some circuits I was running. I am not sure how widespread the issue is, but see the attached image for some strange behavior with the cZ gate.

Is there a place to see the matrix each gate is implementing like before?

Has anyone found similar issues?

This issue does *not* persist when I actually click "run" and select simulator. It seems to only affect the visualizer.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, the issue is that the cZ gates are changing the expected probabilities, even though they should not have any affect in this case?

Comment: That's correct, both the probabilities as well as the actual state (which is what's shown in the picture). I didn't check the density matrix. Control is 0 so each should implement the identity, furthermore two of them in a row should implement the identity regardless of the state of the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for pointing out this! The matrix of the `cZ` gate has been corrected in the in-browser simulator for the visualizations. Simply retry by refreshing your browser.

Comment: Thank you! How about the other part of the question, "Is there a place to see the matrix each gate is implementing like before?". Also, while I've got your ear, is there a way to see my job's position in the queue when running on actual hardware?

Comment: @bRost03 both things will eventually get into the new IBM Q Experience, stay tuned!